# python 3 float precision change

Tags: python

I typed 42.33333333333333333333333333 but I got a different number.

I know python has this precision problem, but I don't want to use Decimal to store the number. Is there a way to resolve this?

By the way, is there a way to read numbers directly from the Decimal object? I am using eval(repr(Decimal("123"))[9:-2]) to read 123 from it. And I discovered my previous problem when I tried  eval(repr(Decimal("42.33333333333333333333333333"))

[image]

Comment: You could use the `fractions` module to store the number as an integer divided by a power of 10, which is true of all terminating decimal numbers. But why don't you want to use `Decimal`? Also, the "precision problem" is not limited to Python but is in many languages. Python has better facilities to overcome that problem than most languages do.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Actually I wrote a program that helps reduce fractions and prints the value of the fraction. And I also have another algorithm using Decimal to give me an accurate result because of the precisioin problem. If the result has the Decimal in it, I think it is less user friendly and I also hope I can use the float number in my further algorithm.

Comment: There is no need to "read numbers directly from the Decimal object". It is itself a number, so you can just use it as such. If you want a float, you can use `float()` on it, if you want an integer use `int()`, etc.

Comment: If you don't want to use `Decimal` there is a library called mpmath which allows arbitrary prection: http://mpmath.org/